# Elegantly using Kernel#open for https via open-uri

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, open-uri, net-http

After requiring `open-uri`, one can conveniently download and use files from the web via `Kernel#open`. However, trying to do this with https results in a root cert error, because ruby doesn't have all the root certs.

This can be solved [like this](http://notetoself.vrensk.com/2008/09/verified-https-in-ruby/), but that's for using a `Net::HTTP` object with a block.

Is there an elegant way to set `use_ssl` and `ca_file` for the `Net::HTTP` library globally, so that it will apply to my whole app, and commands like `Kernel#open`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, after a couple hours I came up with this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/https'

module Net
  class HTTP
    alias_method :original_use_ssl=, :use_ssl=
    def use_ssl=(flag)
      self.ca_file = "/path/to/ca-bundle.crt"
      self.original_use_ssl = flag
    end
  end
end
```

Described more here: https://gist.github.com/996510

Comment: I'd like to add that this worked as a solution for me to get CarrierWave's remote_url function(where you can add attachment via remote url over https) Thanks! https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/carrierwave/HQxayNjVAs4

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an answer to exactly what you asked, but I ended up here while looking for a way to specify `ca_file` with `open-uri`. After digging around in [the `open-uri` source code](https://github.com/ruby/open-uri/blob/master/lib/open-uri.rb#L103), I found that there are various options you can pass to `open`, including one called `ssl_ca_cert`. So to specify CA certificate(s) you can simply use something like:

```rb
URI.open('https://example.com/', ssl_ca_cert: '/path/to/ca-bundle.crt')

# or using older hash syntax:
URI.open('https://example.com/', :ssl_ca_cert => '/path/to/ca-bundle.crt')
```

Comment: nice thanks! probably better solution these days than raw `open`